# How to find ID of Edit button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having one table :

```
           <table id="tblViewNotes" runat="server" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width: 650px;margin-left: 7px;">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Title</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th>Edit</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody></tbody>
                                    </table>
```

I am having two textbox title and description. I am having one save button also and on click of save button, I am appending data to tbody of my table.

```
$('#<%=ibtnSaveTask.ClientID %>').click(function () {

    var title = $('#<%=txtTitle.ClientID %>').val();
    var description = $('#<%=txtContent.ClientID %>').val();

    $('#<%=tblViewNotes.ClientID %> tbody').append('<tr><td>' + title + '</td><td>' + description + '</td><td> <img id="imgEdit" src="../../Images/Edit.gif" style="width:20px; height:20px;" title="Edit" runat="server" /> </td><td>' + description + '</td></tr>');

});
```

So it is working as expected. But now I am not able to get the ID of "imgEdit" button. So following is not working.

`$('#<%=imgEdit.ClientID%>').click(function () { alert("Edit Clicked") });`

Comment: use event delegation

Comment: `#imgEdit` is appended with javascript, it doesn't exist in your C# code, and you can't use `clientID` with it. The real problem is that you're appending multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery 1.7+ you can attach an event handler to a parent element using `.on()`

See http://api.jquery.com/on/

So instead of...

```
$("#imgEdit").click( function() {
    // do something
});
```

You can write...

```
$('body').on('click', '#imgEdit', function() {
    // do something
});
```

**Additionally** it's not good idea to add element with same `ID` instead use counter to make distinct `ID` on each edit button and for click event use `class` instead of `ID` add a `class` to edit button and use that `class` to bind `click` event

Comment: Can you tell me if I edit a row then how to find its index in  order to edit and update?

Comment: @RajeevRanjanTiwary You have to bind a new column with unique id for update particular record make it hide in case you don't want to make it visible and than try to find out give a class to that column and try to find out that class while clicking on edit button if you're not able to do that raise a new question and let me know i'll help you on this

Answer (score 0):

Better you attach event handler too while appending edit button like below.

```
function editNote(){
   alert("Edit Clicked")
}

$('#<%=ibtnSaveTask.ClientID %>').click(function () {

var title = $('#<%=txtTitle.ClientID %>').val();
var description = $('#<%=txtContent.ClientID %>').val();

$('#<%=tblViewNotes.ClientID %> tbody').append('<tr><td>' + title + '</td><td>' + description + '</td><td><a id="btnEdit" href="#" onclick="editNote();"> <img  src="../../Images/Edit.gif" style="width:20px; height:20px;" title="Edit" /> </a> </td><td>' + description + '</td></tr>');

});
```